# no explicit loop to calculate product of list to some modulo in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, do I have to use an explicit loop to calculate the product of elements in a given list (potentially very long) modulo to another number?

Please teach me your elegant approach if you do have. Thanks!

**Edit**

Just to give an example

```
list=Range[2000];Mod[Product[list],32327]
```

The above is very inefficient, because while calculating the products, one could have taken the modulo to make the multipliers smaller.

**Edit 2**

I guess my question relates to how to replace for loop for

```
Module[{ret = initial_value}, For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++, ret = general_function[list[[i]],ret]; ret]
```

given a general function `general_function` and a list `list`.

Comment: Can you show a small example of what you mean? (you do not have to make the list very long in the example ofcourse)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For long lists a divide-and-conquer is typically faster. The idea is to compute the times-mod for the first and second halves, multiply that, and take the mod.

Here is an example. We'll use a list of 10^6 integers, all between 0 and 10^10.

```
SeedRandom[1111111];
len = 6;
max = 10;
list = RandomInteger[10^max, 10^len];
```

Multiplying and taking the modulus, for a slightly larger mod (I wanted to decrease the likelihood that the result was zero):

```
In[119]:= Timing[Mod[Times @@ list, 32327541]]

Out[119]= {1.360000, 8826597}
```

Here is a variant of the sort I described. Trial and error tuning indicated that lists of length 2^9 or so were best done nonrecursively, at least for numbers in the size range indicated above.

```
tmod2[ll_List, m_] := With[{len=Floor[Length[ll]/2]},
  If[len<=256,
    Mod[Times @@ ll, m],
    Mod[tmod2[Take[ll,len],m] * tmod2[Drop[ll,len],m], m]]]

In[120]:= Timing[tmod2[list, 32327541]]

Out[120]= {0.310000, 8826597}
```

When I increase the list length to 10^7 and allow ints from 0 to 10^20, the first method takes 50 seconds and the second one takes 5 seconds. So clearly the scaling is working to our advantage.

For situations where an iteration interleaving two operations might be preferred to divide-and-conquer, one might use Fold as below.

```
tmod3[ll_List, m_] := Fold[Mod[#1*#2,m]&, First[ll], Rest[ll]]
```

While not competitive with tmod2 on long lists, this is faster than multiplying out everything prior to invoking Mod. For length 10^7 and max element 0f 10^20 it takes around 8 seconds to do what tmod2 did in 5.

Comment: Daniel, I am reminded by your use of `Fold` that I wrote you about a year ago regarding a more efficient syntax.  You replied: "There was agreement that it is a good idea. Someone went ahead and implemented it. I'm fairly confident it will remain intact for eventual release, though not version 8.0.1."  Would you please check on the status of that modification?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `Times`? The following

```
list=Range[2000];
Mod[Times@@list,32327]
```

will probably be the most efficient. From a [recent WRI blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/),

> `Times` knows a clever binary splitting trick that can be used when you have a large number of integer arguments. It is faster to recursively split the arguments into two smaller products, (1*2*…*32767)*(32768*…*65536), rather than working through the arguments from first to last. It still has to do the same number of multiplications, but fewer of them involve very big integers, and so, on average, are quicker to do

I'm assuming that `list` in your question is just an example. If you really have to take the product of `n` consecutive integers starting with 1, then `Factorial` will be the fastest. i.e.,

```
Mod[2000!, 32327]
```

Comment: yes, that is definitely an example go generate a long list. I am just wondering in general: if I want to replace something like `Module[{ret = initial_value}, For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++, ret = general_function[list[[i]],ret]; ret]` How to do this without the For loop?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be as much as twice as fast as Daniel's code on my system:

```
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[1*^20, 1*^7];
m = 32327501;

Mod[Times @@ Mod[Times @@@ Partition[list, 50, 50, 1, {}], m], m] // AbsoluteTiming

tmod2[list, m] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.5800904, 21590133}
>
> {3.1081778, 21590133}
> ```

Different partition lengths could be used to tune this for your system and work set.